# 'KeyError' occurs when using prediction function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction, nlp

Im a beginner to machine learning. I found the below code on web for sentiment analysis using imdb dataset.

With this dataset im able to create trained model successfully. During the prediction phase when im trying to make prediction on this  model, getting some "**key error**" response on submission of **strings that are not in the training set**.

Where is the problem happens?. is this model can only predict the sentiment of words which are present in the dataset?. Your help will be highly appreciated.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import text_to_word_sequence

review = "i love stackoverflow"
text = text_to_word_sequence(review)
tmp = []

for word in text:
    tmp.append(word_to_id[word])
    tmp_padded = sequence.pad_sequences([tmp], maxlen=max_review_length)

print("Sentiment score: %s" % (model.predict(array([tmp_padded][0]))[0][0]))
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> KeyError: 'stackoverflow'

Code Reference: https://www.liip.ch/en/blog/sentiment-detection-with-keras-word-embeddings-and-lstm-deep-learning-networks

Comment: There is no word `stackoverflow` in `word_to_id`.

Comment: How to overcome this problem/approach? because the prediction set may have data that is not in training

Comment: Let `word_to_id` contain as many words as possible in all test sets when you create `word_to_id`. This will not affect the training and prediction of the model. Or set the words not included in `word_to_id` to `word_to_id["<UNK>"]`.

Comment: ie, my model will work like a `BagOfWord` sentiment analysis. isnt it?. Since this model is now just counting the sum of positive and negative words in the sentence

Comment: Also how can i achieve this level of accuracy in my model?
https://app.monkeylearn.com/main/classifiers/cl_TWmMTdgQ/

Comment: `BagOfWord` and `Word Embedding` are different. You can refer [Difference between Bag of words and Vector space model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149709/difference-between-bag-of-words-and-vector-space-model). And I'm not sure how accuracy your model and data are. I can't come up with an effective method.